# Phonegap Barcode Scanner Plugin additional result from success parameter

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to add more result apart from **result.text and result.format** on success parameter specifically for **[QR code decoding][1]**? I'm thinking like throwing a QR code mode result or something more useful data.

Example code usage from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Example code in here where:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE6X1.png